# NameError: name 'face_cascade' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, computer-vision

I am trying to detect face in a photo using python

```
# Import the excel file available
import os
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
import warnings
from PIL import Image 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Suppose I have the photo directory and it is stored in `pic_loc`

```
# Load in color image for face detection
image = cv2.imread(pic_loc)

# Convert the image to RGB colorspace
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Make a copy of the original image to draw face detections on
image_copy = np.copy(image)

# Convert the image to gray 
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# Detect faces in the image using pre-trained face dectector
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_image, 1.25, 6)
```

I am getting an error in the last bit where it has to be some error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really want to thank @Divyansh Chaudhary but the solution provided did not solve entirely my problem. The trick was to redefine the

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_eye.xml')
```

The only one that solved it is the following.

```
# Import the excel file available
import os
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
import warnings
from PIL import Image 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Then using the directory of your image you can do

```
# Load in color image for face detection
image = cv2.imread(pic_loc)

# Convert the image to RGB colorspace
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Make a copy of the original image to draw face detections on
image_copy = np.copy(image)

# Convert the image to gray 
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)


face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_eye.xml')

# Detect faces in the image using pre-trained face dectector
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_image, 1.25, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a `cv2.CascadeClassifier()` object.

```
<CascadeClassifier object>  =   cv2.CascadeClassifier(  filename    )
```

[CV2 Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/de5/classcv_1_1CascadeClassifier.html#aaf8181cb63968136476ec4204ffca498)

Here's a small example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread('xyzjpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)


for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you but I am getting this error function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale

Comment: I hope the example will help resolve any further issue